# SQL Arrange blocks of rows in Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Say I have an original output which looks like this (sorted purely by StartTime):

| Name | OrderNo | OpNo | StartTime | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 17345 | op10 | 27/4/22 08:00 | 04:00:00 |
| B | 12727 | op 20 | 27/4/22 11:00 | 02:00:00 |
| A | 18001 | op10 | 27/4/22 13:20 | 01:00:00 |
| B | 17345 | op 20 | 28/4/22 10:17 | 06:00:00 |
| B | 18001 | op 20 | 29/4/22 13:00 | 04:00:00 |
| C | 17345 | op 30 | 3/5/22 16:20 | 08:00:00 |
| C | 18001 | op 30 | 5/5/22 13:00 | 09:00:00 |

How would it be possible to order the rows by OrderNo, then by OpNo, and then by the StartTime of the lowest OpNo in each OrderNo? So it would look like this:

| Name | OrderNo | OpNo | StartTime | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 17345 | op10 | 27/4/22 08:00 | 04:00:00 |
| B | 17345 | op 20 | 28/4/22 10:17 | 06:00:00 |
| C | 17345 | op 30 | 3/5/22 16:20 | 08:00:00 |
| B | 12727 | op 20 | 27/4/22 11:00 | 02:00:00 |
| A | 18001 | op10 | 27/4/22 13:20 | 01:00:00 |
| B | 18001 | op 20 | 29/4/22 13:00 | 04:00:00 |
| C | 18001 | op 30 | 5/5/22 13:00 | 09:00:00 |

I understand it's easy enough to do the Order By OrderNo, OpNo to get the rows sorted into 'blocks' of each OrderNo with asc (or desc) OpNo. But the problem I'm then having is how do I order each of these 'blocks' by the StartTime of the lowest OpNo in each of these 'blocks'?

Hopefully I've made sense?

Comment: So to clarify, your issue is that the `StartTime` column actually contains the text string `start` is that right? Or are you adding that as part of your Select clause?

Comment: Please start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided. 
Also a view of your expected output based on the table data you show as an example.

Comment: Ah sorry let me fix that - there is no 'start' in that column, it is just a datetime

Comment: It would reaaly help if you also showed us your current query

Comment: Honestly not trying to come across rude, but why does the other data help? To get to this point it's quite a jumble of joining large tables with many fields, and the query is quite complex so it feels to me like adding all of the schema and the query would dilute the question and make it harder to read?

Comment: MySql supports [first_value()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) since 8.0. What is your version?

Comment: @Serg I do have first_value() available to me, how would you suggest I apply that here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using first_value

```
select *
from (
    select *, first_value(StartTime) over(partition by OrderNo order by OpNo) blockStart    
    from mytable
) t
order by blockStart, OrderNo, OpNo
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Question though, what does the outer SELECT clause do in this instance?

Comment: Just for calrity. MySql supports using window functions directly in an ORDER BY clause as well.